# Mocking base class method in Hippomocks

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, hippomocks

Let's say we have the following classes `A` and `B`:

```
class A
{
    virtual void Init() { DoSomething(); }
};

class B : public A
{
    virtual void Init() { DoSomethingSpecial(); A::Init(); }
};
```

In our unit test we only want to test `B`, that is to test using [Hippomocks](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/hippomocks/wiki/Home) that calling `B::Init()` will actually call `DoSomethingSpecial()`:

```
B* b_p = new B();
m_mockRepository_p->ExpectCall(b_p, DoSomethingSpecial);
b_p->Init();
```

Now we don't want to expect all calls from `A`'s `Init()` so we'd like to write something like:

```
m_mockRepository_p->ExpectCall(b_p, A::Init);
```

The last expectation causes an unhandled exception which I think is okay since we are mixing the method we're calling with its base version we want to expect. Casting `b_p` to an `A` doesn't help.

Is there any solution to that particular use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... This is an interesting one. I think there's no solution to this. The call to A::Init isn't done via the virtual function table (as you know explicitly which one to call) so it falls under non-virtual functions, which you cannot mock.

A complicating factor for adding this is that if you took the address of A::Init on B you'd still get the vtable pointer, so you couldn't even replace the function if you wanted to (say, using the C function mocking logic).

I can only recommend the generic refactoring solutions to solve this - make A and B independant classes, make B contain A (private inheritance) or extract an interface from A and B and turn B into a decorator. The last sounds best but it depends on what A and B actually are...